# Which is the best way to add a button?

Tags: android, android-button

I'm  new to android development. I've a doubt. 
I know that you can add a button and initialize it like

```
Button b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

and I can also give a unction name in the XML file.

```
  android:onClick="click_event"
```

My doubt is, which is the best and efficient way? 
like it says that its better to use @string resource instead of a hard-coded one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are confused. The examples you give are two different things.

**Adding a Button**

This line

```
Button b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

doesn't add a `Button`. It declares and initializes an instance of `Button` which refers to a `Button` in your currently inflated xml which has an `id` of `button1`

So in your xml you would have somewhere

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     <!-- other properties -->
/>
```

You can add a `Button` programmatically with

```
Button bt1 = new Button(this);
// give it properties
```

But it is generally easier to do in xml because here you have to programmatically give it parameters, properties, and add it to an inflated `layout`

**OnClick**

As far as the `onClick()` it depends on what you feel is the easiest and best in your situation. I like to declare it in the xml like that often but you can do it several ways. Using this method you just have to be sure that you have a function like this that is `public` and takes only one parameter and that parameter must be a `View`

```
 public void clickEvent(View v)
{
    // code here
}
```

I also changed the name so your xml would be like

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     <!-- other properties -->
     android:onClick="clickEvent"/>
```

You also can set `onClick()` in your Java with something like

```
Button b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // code here
    }
});
```

or

```
 Button b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b1.setOnClickListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // code here
    }
```

Note that the last way you will need to add `implements OnClickListener` in your `Activity` declaration

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
```

You can also create your own click `Listener` by changing it to something like

```
b1.setOnClickListener(myBtnClick);
```

then create an instance of it with something like

```
public OnClickListener myBtnClick = new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // click code here      
    }
};
```

You can use this for multiple `Button`s and switch on the `id` or check the `View` param to know which `Button` was clicked or create separate `Listeners` for different `Button`s.