# Clickable textview not working

Tags: android, onclick, textview

I've looked around SO for how to make a textview clickable, and I am doing everything they say but the onClick method is still not being called. Here's my code from the activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.month_january:
        Log.w("onclick", "yes");
        TextView temp = (TextView) findViewById(v.getId());
        temp.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        switchNumberDays(31);
        break;
    case R.id.month_february:...
```

I put the log in to see whether the onClick was being called when I clicked on the textview, and nothing was logged. Here's my xml for that specific textview:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/month_january"
            android:text="January" />
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Did you register the listener with your textview? Something like `textView.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() { ... })`. Show the code where you assign the onClick to the textview.

Comment: @csmckelvey I thought that you could also just have one onClick method and switch the id's

Comment: You can, but the listener must be registered to _something_. There are many ways to accomplish this, that's why I must see how you have implemented it. I need to see more code (not the code inside your onClick, the code outside it).

Comment: @csmckelvey oh i see now i added the tv.setOnClickListener(this) to the onCreate and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319711/android-eclipse-which-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-button/18319759#18319759) about different ways to implement an `OnClickListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your class is implementing the `onClickListener` interface, be sure that you register it with your textview once it is created.

```
public class someActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView();
        textView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hi please do in this way because i think yours listeners are not used properly in yours code..

For making your TextView clickable just add this to your TextView:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

after that you can set onClickListener to it by using this:

```
yourTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do your work here
        }
    });
```

or an another way is also there

```
public class sticks extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener { 
  private TextView tv1; 
  private TextView tv2;
  private TextView tv3     

  @Override 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1); 
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2); 
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3); 

    // bind listeners
    tv1.setOnTouchListener(this); 
    tv2.setOnTouchListener(this); 
    tv3.setOnTouchListener(this); 

  } 

  @Override 
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
    // check which textview it is and do what you need to do

    // return true if you don't want it handled by any other touch/click events after this
    return true; 
  } 
}
```