# How to close Android activity and return to previous/main activity?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I'm trying to understand tutorials with using intents to open up a java.class activity. I can manage to open up the activity using this code:

```
    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, settingmenu.class);

    startActivity(in);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    finish();
```

In that activity, I plan to have edittexts to be used in the settings, but first I want to understand how to simply RETURN to the previous activity. My onClick method for my buttons plays a method that is this:

```
public void cancel()
{
    this.finish();
    return;
}
```

However, when pressing the button, the app crashes. What am I doing differently? Several tutorials say use finish(), but I feel off.

Comment: You should show logcat output for crash for an accurate response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to understand how to simply RETURN to the previous activity

Don't call `finish()` in your first `Activity`. Then when the user presses the "Back" button the second `Activity` will be closed and taken off the stack and the `onResum()` of the first `Activity` will be called.

```
 Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, settingmenu.class);

startActivity(in);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
// finish();  don't call this and the Activity will remain on the stack
```

As far as the crash, you would need to provide the logcat and quite possibly more of your code

You will probably want to read about [the Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) which will go a long way in understanding how `Activities` are are placed on and popped off. Also, there is a very good talk from I believe Romain Guy at one of the older Google I/O conferences about this which is very helpful. I will try to post but you can Google those terms and you will find it.

[Activity Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

[Google I/O Navigation and stack](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/5698617)  Not who I thought it was but definitely worth watching.

Comment: Am I supposted to add a onResume method on my first activity? I haven't done that.

Comment: No, its an `Activity` method which you can `Override` if needed. Posted link to docs

Comment: Looking at the logcat, it said that it couldn't find my method that was on my onClick method. I don't think I added an onClickListener for that button... so I Think thats the reason why.

Comment: Probably. You might want to check the [Button Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html). If you are setting the `onClick` in xml then your method must be 1) public 2) have `void` return type and 3) accept a `View` as its one and only `param`

Comment: Went back and edited it, its now: public void save(View view) { finish(); }, but it still gives the eddor how it cant find the method. I need to figure out onClickListeners

Comment: Did you look at the `Button` docs I posted in my previous comment? Also, [See this answer I gave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319711/android-eclipse-which-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-button/18319759#18319759) about implementing different `onClick()` options.

Answer (score 0):

When you use "finish", you simply destroy the activity and it won't be in the stack, if you want to go to previous activity, you need to use another intent to startactivity, or don't use "finish" after intent.

Comment: If I use another intent to go back, won't that make two instances of the activty since it was created, and it was made again?

Comment: you destroy it by using finish, it will be only one activity

Answer (score 0):

To solve my issue, I got rid of the android:onClick="save()", and instead made an onclicklistener in the onCreate method in my 2nd activity. Testing it, it worked.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.settingmenu);

    Button tt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
    tt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){private void onClick(){
Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, Main.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   
startActivity(intent);}});
```