# Runtime equivalent to (XML) android:onClick?

Tags: android

One way to implement a button handler in Android since 1.6 is to put this in the XML where the button is declared . . .

```
...
android:onClick="TheButtonHandler"
...
```

and then just put the handler routine in the Activity class . . .

```
   public void TheButtonHandler(View target) {
    // ... button handler code
 }
```

I have some Android code where all the buttons are created in Java at runtime during initialization, not in XML, but I want to do the same stuff as the above XML including specifying the button handler.   **N.B.** that I want the button handlers to be in their own separate routines just as they would if I were declaring them in the XML in the above example, I don't want button handler code embedded in the my initialization code.

I've seen examples of using *setOnClickListener*, but the handler code was always embedded inline, e.g.,

```
  demoButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
               // ... button handler code     
  }});
```

... which is where I don't want it because that would put the button handler code up where the buttons are initialized.   What's the Java runtime equivalent of *android:onClick* ?

Comment: All rounds will lead to the usage of `View.setOnClickListener()`... I hope there is no alternative...

Comment: @GopalRao why do you hope it?

Comment: Who voted for this to be closed, and why?

Comment: @blackbelt I didn't get you? is there any alternative for `android:onClick` for Views that are created dynamically other than `View.setOnClickListener()`?

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319711/android-eclipse-which-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-button/18319759#18319759)

Comment: no, those are the only ones. But why "hope"? @GopalRao

Comment: It's just an anonymous class. You can give it a name as Jay S. described  in the answer below. then you can use the same listener for several buttons, if you check the id

Comment: This is actually pretty interesting.  I'm assuming some sort of compiler magic goes on to link the method?

Comment: @trevor-e magic for the xml way, or the anonymous class?

Comment: I think he means the magic is stuff you get for free using XML.  That's too bad -  before this I was under the impression there was a 1:1 correspondence between XML tags/attributes and class members

Comment: @NickT For the XML way.  laalto's answer clears it up and it makes sense that it uses reflection since `onClick:` is just a normal attribute.  I thought it was at the compiler level since I vaguely remembering getting errors for not having defined the method it points to, but maybe that was just the IDE talking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent is `setOnClickListener()` and `View.OnClickListener`.

If you [examine the platform source](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java#3797), you'll see that methods defined with `onClick` attribute are transformed to a an `OnClickListener` that invokes the named method via Java reflection.

> I've seen examples of using setOnClickListener, but the handler code was always embedded inline ... which is where I don't want it because that would put the button handler code up where the buttons are initialized

You can have your `OnClickListener`s e.g. as member variables like this:

```
private OnClickListener mClickListener = new OnClickListener() { ... };

//

    view.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
```

to have the initialization and click handling in separate places.

Comment: I'll take your word for it - I'm not going to try to read 19K lines of source code - the platform does a bunch of magic for free if we use the XML but not if we do it in java.   So if we do it in java we have to add our own layers of complexity - named or anonymous classes, tags, case statements, or whatever.   So the answer to my question is "**no** there is no equivalent".

Comment: @user316117 It's really just ~40 lines of code since he linked to the approriate switch case.  Worth checking out how they do it imo.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //....

        myButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
        myButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
        myButton3.setOnClickListener(this);
        myButton4.setOnClickListener(this);



        myButton1.setTag(0);
        myButton2.setTag(1);
        myButton3.setTag(2);
        myButton4.setTag(3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do your stuff
        switch ((int) v.getTag()) {

            case 0:
                //First button pressed;
                break;
            case 1:
                //Second button pressed;
                break;
            case 2:
                //Third button pressed;
                break;
            case 3:
                //Fourth button pressed;
                break;
            default:
                //Unknown value, handle an error
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //....

        myButton1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               // ... button handler code     
            }
        });

        myButton2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               // ... button handler code     
            }
        });

        myButton3.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               // ... button handler code     
            }
        });

        myButton4.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               // ... button handler code     
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this one.  One handler per Activity?    In my Activity I have a 2x3 grid of buttons (6 buttons)   In the XML I could declare 6 handlers all in the same Activity.    So I'm not sure in what sense this is equivalent.

Comment: What you could so is either inline your `OnClickListener`'s, or when you get your buttons you could call `myButton.setTag((int) SomeId);`, then in `onClick` run a `switch` on the tag. I'll update my post now with an example.

Comment: Okay see above code for examples on both methods, also there's nothing stopping you from inlining your `onClick`, then just calling `MyHandlingFunction();` inside the `onClick` to separate up your logic. that's probably the method I'd go along.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you've put into this so I gave you a +1 but I think what you're **really** saying is that there's **really** no equivalent to what I get with the XML.  The tagging approach is a workaround to simulate some aspects of doing it in XML, but with the added complexity of tagging and case code.

Comment: Yeah that's the best workaround I can think of, but for simplicity I think using `android:onClick` is the best. Also see Iaalto's answer, that's also another way you could to it, it keeps a readable reference to what the method does (like a method name would), but I wouldn't says it's equivalent to XML.

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't have to include them inline if that is what you are requesting.
You can create your own class such as:

```
MyButtonClickListener implements Button.OnClickListener
{
  ...
}
```

and this can be defined elsewhere.  Then you can reference it in the initialization code similarly but not taking up as much space for readability as such.

```
demoButton.setOnClickListener(new MyButtonClickListener());
```

if that is indeed your question.

Comment: Sure, but that's still a lot messier and more complicated than the android:OnClick in the XML.  So I wouldn't really call it equivalent.  Most things in the XML have an equivalent in Java.  You can set the color or the text or the enabled state (etc, etc) in 1 line both in the java and XML.

Comment: This does *set* the listener in one line. You still have to write the method, even if you're setting it in XML.

Comment: But this implements a separate class for each button handler, right?   In the XML case there's just the main Activity class and separate routines for each handler.  So I don't see how this is "equivalent".

Answer (score 0):

As @laalto already pointed out, Android View itself simply takes the name of the handler and uses Java reflections to create an OnClickListener object. I digged the code out from View.java and wrapped it in a separate object:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;

public class ViewOnClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener{

    Activity mActivity;
    Method mHandler;
    ViewOnClickHandler(Activity activity, View view, String handlerName){
        mActivity = activity;
        try {
            mHandler = activity.getClass().getMethod(handlerName, View.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            int id = view.getId();
            String idText = id == View.NO_ID ? "" : " with id '"
                    + mActivity.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id) + "'";
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find a method " +
                    handlerName + "(View) in the activity "
                    + activity.getClass() + " for onClick handler"
                    + " on view " + view.getClass() + idText, e);
        }           
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            mHandler.invoke(mActivity, v);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute non "
                    + "public method of the activity", e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute "
                    + "method of the activity", e);
        }
    }

    static void set(Activity activity, View view, String handlerName){
        view.setOnClickListener(new ViewOnClickHandler(activity, view, handlerName));

    }
}
```

If you put this code in a package of your choice and import the class into your activity, the code from your sample can shrink down to:

```
ViewOnClickHandler.set(this, demoButton, "TheButtonHandler");
```