# I have 10 ImageButtons how can I get them to do different things with one method

Tags: android

I have 10 Imagebuttons which are the same as the one below named badvs1 to badvs5 and goodvs1 to goodvs5

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/badvs1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/heroselected"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="changeHero"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/prettypicture" />
```

Onclick they do this and everything works fine for the first button

```
public void changeHero(View v) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < heroImages.length; i++){
        if (badagainst[position][0] == heroImages[i]){
            position = i;
            heroSelect = heroImages[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    setImages();
}
```

It only works for the first imagebutton as badagainst[position][0] is the image that is associated with that imagebutton. I could just create the same thing 9 more times changing that one variable badagainst[position][1] / badagainst[position][2] ... goodagainst[position][0] / goodagainst[position][1] etc etc. But is there a better way where I can just make it so the button selected will determine this.

I'm pretty new to programming and have not fully grasped everything yet.

Comment: Do you need to check it against the array or can you check which button was clicked?

Comment: At the moment I am checking it against the array. But if there is a way to get the image ID off the button I could do that instead. But the image id in the array of arrays (either badagainst or goodagainst), does have to match the id in the heroImages array

Comment: To check against the button pressed [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319711/android-eclipse-which-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-button/18319759#18319759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given proper explaination.

You can store objects associated with views as tags.

For Eg:

```
v.setTag("some info"); 

String info = v.getTag();
```

Assuming, you only need to make the code shorter instead of just copy pasting things-

Try this-

```
public void changeHero(View v) {

    // To get name of the button pressed
    String buttonName = (String) getResources().getResourceName(v.getId());
    int index = Integer.parseInt(buttonName.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
    if(buttonName.contains("good")){
        for (int i = 0; i < heroImages.length; i++){
            if (goodagainst[position][index] == heroImages[i]){
                position = i;
                heroSelect = heroImages[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < heroImages.length; i++){
            if (badagainst[position][index] == heroImages[i]){
                position = i;
                heroSelect = heroImages[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    setImages();
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I need to do. I was confused with the link given in other explanation. Will test it and let you know

Comment: Ok this is almost working now. I had to add the package name before buttonName.startsWith("viewtiful.jon.heroselecter:id/good") I found this out by using a toast message. Its the next line that I can't get working. I presume It replaces all apart from the last character,  Which will be the correct number for the index if i have 0-4 instead of 1-5 and changes it into an int. Am I supposed to replace the "\\w" with something else?

Comment: I used 3 seperate replace statments one being the package name up until :/ the others being goodvs and badvs. This just left the number.  Which I goggled and found Interger.valueOf(buttonNumber.toString());  Button number was what I called the new string that had all the characters taken out. Thanks so much for your help saved me a lot of time

Comment: I am glad that helped .. I've updated my answer to extract only digits from the string and replaced startsWith with contains method.

Answer (score 0):

This should be in the function that your buttons are set or you can implement on click listener for all the buttons and get a callback in onClick of buttons in the class.

int id = v.getId();

```
switch(id)
{
   case R.id.button1:
        //your code;
        //break;
   case R.id. button2:
        //your code;
        //break;
   default:
}
```