# Android onClick event not working

Tags: android

I am pretty new to the Android Development and I am still reading the documentation. By the way I am trying to add an event when I click a button. Here's the code:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
  android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
  android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
  android:text="Execute"
  android:onClick="onClickRadGard" />
```

And I declare the onClickRadGrad in this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    final Button buttonx = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    buttonx.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks

        }
    });

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

I don't know where's the problem because Eclipse tells me this: 
[image]

Do you have any suggestion? You can find the full code here: [link](http://pastebin.com/iYyxU6ZE).

Comment: Since you have `android:onClick="onClickRadGard"` defined for your `Button` in xml, you don't need to set an `OnClickListener` in Java. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319711/android-eclipse-which-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-button/18319759#18319759)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several suggestions:

you declared `android:onClick="onClickRadGard"` in your xml. That means that your activity will expect to find a method with the following signature:

```
public void onClickRadGard(View view) {

}
```

if it is not declared your application will crash. This method will be invoked when you press on your `android:id="@+id/button1"`, so you do not need to call `setOnClickListener` on it.

About the compile time error you are getting, I took a look to the the code you posted in the link. Those two lines have to be defined after `setContentView`, in the body of `onCreate`

```
final Button buttonx = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

buttonx.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    //other code
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
buttonx.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on clicks

    }
});
```

Place your above code inside `onCreate()` below `setContentView(..)`.

Also since you are defining an `onClickListener` in your activity, you can remove`android:onClick="onClickRadGard"` from xml.

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to either just specify the `android:onClick="onClickRadGard"` and then do

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    ...

    public void onClickRadGard(View v)
    {
       ///code here
    }
}
```

Or if you **don't** specify it in the XML, but only with a listener:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    ....

    Button button1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveState)
    {
        super.onCreate(saveState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                 //code here
            }
        });
     }
     ...
}
```

Or as such:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    ....

    Button button1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveState)
    {
        super.onCreate(saveState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View view)
     {
         if(view == button1)
         {
            ///code here
         }
     }
}
```