# OnClick listener implementation not working

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm using `onClick()` method by implementing `OnClickListener` class. Using below code but it does not work! There are no errors but it doesn't work. When I click on the button nothing happens. What is wrong?

```
package com.behnam.PhoneCh.main;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText mainEt;
    TextView mainTv;
    Button   mainBtn;
    Button   mainBtn2;
    String   vaje;
    Javab    javab;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mainEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mainTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mainBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mainBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        vaje = new String();
        javab = new Javab();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View aaaaa) {
        switch (aaaaa.getId()) {

            case R.id.   Log.i("mylog", "start button1");
                vaje = mainEt.getText().toString();
                mainTv.setText(javab.startJ(vaje));
                break;
            case R.id.button2:             
                int c = 3;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You never set your listener on your `Buttons`

```
mainBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

You will need to add this for all of the `Buttons` that you want to use the `onClick()`.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319711/android-eclipse-which-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-button/18319759#18319759) for different ways of handling `onClick()`

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mainEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mainTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mainBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mainBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mainBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    mainBtn2.setOnClickListener(this); 
    vaje = new String();
    javab = new Javab();

}


@Override
public void onClick(View aaaaa) {
    switch (aaaaa.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1;
            Log.i("mylog", "start button1");
            vaje = mainEt.getText().toString();
            mainTv.setText(javab.startJ(vaje));
            break;
        case R.id.button2:             
            int c = 3;
            break;
    }

}
```

Change your `onCreate` and `onClick` with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Button btMain = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btMain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doStuff();
        }
});
```

This is the best way to start understanding how the listeners work.

Comment: If you are going to say this is the best way then you should at least explain *why*. There are several ways to do it but I'm not sure you can say there is *one best way*. It depends on the situation and the developer.

Comment: Obviously. You are strictly right. But if you develop an Android app, frequently you have more than one View/Button. So a switch with very cases is tedious to read/understand/implement. More difficult if you are a newbie developer.

Comment: it does not explain why it is *the best* way

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText mainEt;
TextView mainTv;
Button   mainBtn;
Button   mainBtn2;
String   vaje;
Javab    javab;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mainEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mainTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mainBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mainBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mainBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    mainBtn2 .setOnClickListener(this);
    vaje = new String();
    javab = new Javab();

}

// And then you can use
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1:
            // Dome some stuff on click of button 1
            break;
        case R.id.button2:             
            // Dome some stuff on click of button 2
            break;
    }

 }
}
```