# Button onClick error...Could not find a method

Tags: java, android, android-activity, buttonclick

I can't seem to start a new `Activity` from my `Button`, I have searched here for answers, but can't seem to resolve the problem. I hope someone has an easy solution. Thanks In advance.

Here is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method openSearch(View) in the 
activity class dk.mathias.splitcab.MainActivity 
for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnStartSearch'
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void openSearch(){
    Intent openSearchIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartSearch.class);
    startActivity(openSearchIntent);
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".StartSearch"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start_search" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="dk.mathias.splitcab.STARTSEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/StartSearch"
    android:id="@+id/btnStartSearch"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvWelcome"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvWelcome"
    android:onClick="openSearch"

    />
```

**StartSearch.java**

```
public class StartSearch extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_search);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your  StartSearch.class activity?

Comment: so what happens? errors, exceptions, logs ?

Comment: It looks about right...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your method signature

```
public void openSearch(){
```

it should have one, and only one param, which is a `View`.

Change it to

```
public void openSearch(View v){
```

`v` obviously can be anything you want it to be but you should make it something meaningful like `v`, `view`, etc...

[From the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

> In order for this to work, the method must be public and accept a View as its only parameter.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319711/android-eclipse-which-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-button/18319759#18319759) for a more detailed description of adding `Buttons` and `OnClick`

Answer (score 1):

First make a reference to your button

```
    search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartSearch);
```

Then implement the onClick listner for the button as below

```
        search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent openSearchIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartSearch.class);
             startActivity(openSearchIntent)
        }
    });
```

Make sure you remove this line from your XML file

```
 android:onClick="openSearch"
```

Comment: Why would you suggest this? Everything is fine with the way the OP is doing it besides missing the param in the method

Comment: @codeMagic - Your answer is perfectly fine and I have a +1 as well My intension to suggest this is to know the implementation of onClick Listeners

Comment: I'm not concerned with the +1, the point is that you make it sound like it is being done wrong with the way the OP is doing it. I see this all the time with `onClick`. I don't think we should just tell the OP another way without explaining what is being done wrong. It is confusing.

Comment: I Chose the other answer for best answer because it was the easiest fix. I Am sure that your solution also works and therefore I have given it an upvote. Thanks for the reply!