# How do I open a button another activity with another button?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have made successfully my Imagebutton to open anther activity but the issue is by using the same method on another ImageButton it comes up with an error saying the method is already used in "Main Activity".

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
      private static ImageButton ImageButton_sbm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickImageButtonListener();
    }

    public void OnClickImageButtonListener() {
        ImageButton_sbm = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        ImageButton_sbm.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("saintbedeslytham.saintbedes.event");
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }

        );

    }

    private static ImageButton ImageButton2_sbm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickImageButtonListener();
    }

    public void OnClickImageButtonListener() {
        ImageButton_sbm = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        ImageButton_sbm.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("saintbedeslytham.saintbedes.news");
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }

        );

    }
```

How, if anything, can I apply another method for the `"saintbedeslytham.saintbedes.news"`

Comment: Is that last half of code in a separate activity?

Comment: @codeMagic I'm afraid it's in the same class

Comment: So do I move it to another class?

Comment: Yes, you need a separate class which `extends Activity`

Comment: @codeMagic No, if he wants both buttons in the same screen

Comment: @Gorcyn sure but he is calling startActivity() and trying to use that code. The intentions weren't completely clear but it looks like he's trying to combine two activites into one, hence the two `onCreate()`s

Comment: Exactly, I want to have the buttons on the same screen.

Comment: He has 2 different `ImageButton`s in the same screen that would trigger different activities

Comment: Ok then remove the duplicate `onCreate()` and change the name of one of the click functions. [I gave an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319711/android-eclipse-which-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-button/18319759#18319759) which may help you with setting the onClick listeners

Comment: And have an upvote because, while the problem *should* have been fairly obvious, it wasn't a completely poorly written question from a new user. Take it easy, folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that you cannot create two method with the same definition.
You have two:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);
```

and two:

```
public void OnClickImageButtonListener();
```

You can't have 2 methods with the same definition for 2 simple reasons.
Imagine 2 people with the same name, call for their name.

- Who will answer?
- Who are you calling?

**Edit:**
So you can:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prepareClicks();
    }

    private void prepareClicks() {
        findViewById(R.id.imageButton).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("saintbedeslytham.saintbedes.event");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
        findViewById(R.id.imageButton2).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("saintbedeslytham.saintbedes.news");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so I need to change the definition for each methods

Comment: Or you can prepare these click listeners in the same method

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prepareClicks();
    }

    private void prepareClicks() {
        findViewById(R.id.imageButton).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("saintbedeslytham.saintbedes.event");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
        findViewById(R.id.imageButton2).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("saintbedeslytham.saintbedes.news");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Yup the method worked.

Thanks for the replies,

(Done by Gorcyn)

Comment: If the answer by Gorcyn fixed your problem, it is appropriate to accept his answer by ticking the checkmark next to that answer instead of reposting the same code. It helps him, the community, and you.