# Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler

Tags: android, onclick

I don't know whats happening in my application now.
I'm getting this message `Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler`

And everything is right, I think...
Here's my activity xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#9EC5E2"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    tools:context="com.tumta.henrique.teste.view.LoginActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_campos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:text="@string/text_usuario"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_usuario"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="15" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:text="@string/text_senha"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_senha"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="15"
            android:password="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_campos"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_cancelar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Cancelar" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's my Activity:

```
package com.tumta.henrique.teste.view;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.tumta.henrique.teste.R;
import com.tumta.henrique.teste.model.ConsultaLogin;

public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ConsultaLogin.ConsultaConcluidaLoginListener {


    EditText txtUsuario, txtSenha;
    ActionBar actionbar;
    Button btnOk, btnCancelar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new ConsultaLogin(this).execute();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        txtUsuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_usuario);
        txtSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_senha);
        actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.hide();
        btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        btnCancelar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_cancelar);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        //ConsultaLogin.login = txtUsuario.getText().toString();
        //ConsultaLogin.senha = txtSenha.getText().toString();
        //new ConsultaLogin(this).execute();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConsultaConcluida(String result) {
        if (result == null) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Erro");
            builder.setMessage("Usuario ou Senha Incorreto!");
            builder.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    txtUsuario.getText().clear();
                    txtSenha.getText().clear();
                    txtUsuario.requestFocus();
                }
            });
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know whats wrong here. Can someone help me?

**EDIT**
My complete error stacktrace:

```
06-18 08:40:40.027  27976-27976/com.tumta.henrique.teste E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tumta.henrique.teste, PID: 27976
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClickOk(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button_ok'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onClickOk [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4000)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: `implements View.OnClickListener` <-- add that. Actually, you have more problems. Look at the link at the top and it will walk you through adding an `onClick()`. Choose one way. You are mixing them, it appears. And I wouldn't name it `onClick` if you are doing it in xml

Comment: I'm not sure it's exactly a dupe so I'll reopen but you may want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319711/android-eclipse-which-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-button) anyway and take my advice on the naming in your xml

Comment: Post your complete stacktrace from the crash.

Comment: @codeMagic I was using the same method for both buttons. Using `switch case`.. But onlt `btnCancelar` was working, wich the only code was `finish()`.. I've already tried to change the method name, but it didn't work..

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct xml because the stacktrace says it's looking for the method `onClickOk` notice the "Ok". If it is the correct xml try cleaning and rebuilding the project

Comment: @codeMagic I've chaged the name also in the xml.. Change the name to test.. but it also didn't work..

Comment: Is it the same error message or different in any way? Also, have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project like I previously suggested?

Comment: @codeMagic Yes, always the same error message.. And I've tried all that you suggested, but nothing worked..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the Solution.. I don't know why, but after doing some search I saw some posts saying that it's an issue on Android 5.0 or higher.. 
The solution was removing the `theme` tag from my `layout.xml` file.

Comment: Weird, what a terrible bug!

Comment: weired, also have to remove style from all root and parent layouts

Answer (score 1):

I got an Activity as a Dialog, so i can't remove the "theme" tag.

When extending `Activity` (not `AppActivityCompat`) i had to set a listener on my button, instead using the `onClick` provided by xml editor:

```
Button myBtn = findViewById(R.id.myButton);
myBtn.setOnClickListener((v) -> myMethod(v));
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing `materialThemeOverlay` from clicked view style.